# App Delegate not being called in SwiftUI project

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, appdelegate

I have a straightforward `AppDelegate` setup in a small SwiftUI project, but the code is not getting called.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure() // Never hit
        
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct card_uploaderApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        // register app delegate for Firebase setup
        @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
        
        WindowGroup {
            TabContainerView()
        }
    }
}
```

Is some sort of file corruption preventing the app delegate code from getting hit?

Comment: Move UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor outside of the body.